# Older ASP.NET projects best practice on DB objects

Tags: asp.net, database

Stack flagged this Question as an opnion! so here is a redo of it.

The first answer I got before being shutdown was.
" never return a data reader, return a data table"

Your suggestion looks exactly like this example.
learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/…

For this example,
A DataTable is create in a called function GetCustomers() and returned to the caller.

The caller creates a DataReader from the DataTable in a using() so the DataReader is cleaned up
BUT the DataTable is never disposed of.

How to handle disposing of it?
THIS is the main -exact- question I am (trying!) to ask. TX

Also the GetReader()
Does a new DataTable();
and then returns a reference? To it.
How does this get cleaned up once the
DoSomething() finishes?

```
    private void DoSomething()
    {
        string Txt, sql;
        sql = "Select * from table;";
        DataTableReader dr = GetReader(sql);
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Txt = dr["Txt"] + "";
        }
    }

    private DataTableReader GetReader(string sql)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DB"]);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt.CreateDataReader();
    }
```

Comment: If you're worried about "best practices", you should consider re-writing these ASP.NET Framework apps altogether in modern ASP.NET Core, instead. In the meantime, these old code snippets sound like they are 'good enough practice' to have not caused a problem in all these years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you did not post the GetReader function.

However, the GetDataTable?

Yes, all such routines should cleaned up. Thus, that code could be written as:

```
    public DataTable GetDataTable(string sql)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql,
                                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DB"] ))
        {
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

So, yes, the correct approach is to ALWAYS wrap your connection, or adapter code with a connection in a using block. Thus, that will ensure everything is all cleaned up.

As you note, the site been running for years without issue, and that's just a great testimony as to how well .net cleans up itself, and runs anyway.

.net has a built-in connection pool system, and it automatic recycles the connection pool for you. So, in theory you can write some less then ideal code, and everything continues to work rather well.

In fact, before .net connection pools, then the developer had to write code to maintain active connections. Now, since they are pooled, then with a using block, the connections are still in the pool even when disposed in code, and thus the “old school” concepts of keeping a connection open all the time don’t apply anymore.

However, such code should still have using blocks.

Often you can get away say with a command object, or even a data adaptor object NOT wrapped in a using block, but if the connection object is used in that code or created? Then a using block should be used.

In that second sample, a separate connection object not being created, and thus the using block should apply to the data adaptor.

The first example is more problematic, since returning a reader means the table stays open. In that case, a dr dispose at the end of the code routine should be used.

I thus never return a data reader, and would have returned a data table, of which the 2nd example code shows how (and then use a for/each on the datatable.rows in place of a while (dr.read).

Comment: " never return a data reader, return a data table"
Your suggestion looks exactly like this example.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.createdatareader?view=net-8.0

For this example above, 
A DataTable is create in a called function GetCustomers() and returned to the caller.
The caller creates a DataReader from the DataTable in a using() so the DataReader is cleaned up BUT the DataTable is never disposed of. Should it not also be disposed of and if so how? THIS is the main exact question I am (trying!) to ask. TX

Comment: A datatable is returned, and like most local vars in a routine, we don't as a general rule have to clean them up, no more then say dispposing some string var or class.  Connections are VERY different matter, and they deserve more love and care. So, I suppose if one wanted to, you could dispose the data table, but I never bothered and never had a issue, and don't think it matters much at all if you dispose ANY of your vars used in a routine. .So, the love and care issue centers around connections - they need to be in a using block, and thus automatic disposed. Other objects? Not a worry

Comment: the big difference here is that a datareader don't work UNLESS the connection remains open, and thus the big difference. As noted, this is why I don't like nor suggest returning a datareader, since during use, it requires a open connection. Thus, if one needs or wants to use a data reader, then that should be wrapped in a using block - not that some routine returns a open reader + connection. And if you using a routine that does return a reader, then wrap that reader in a using block that then is set from that routine returning the data reader (which has that connection object also)

Answer (score 1):

If something implements `IDisposable`, then you should make sure it is disposed of properly.

Either by using a `using` block (if it is used within a method), or by implementing IDisposable yourself (if it is used at class level) so you can dispose of it when your class is `Dispose()`d